# Anatomically correct quadrupedal arthropod?

Tags: science-based, biology, anatomy, insectoid, anatomically-correct

Most arthropods have at least six legs. Some mites have four and some insects have none, but for the most part, they have six or more.

What would the anatomy of a large quadrupedal arthropod be like?
I am thinking of large insect-small mammal size, terrestrial, and predatory.

Comment: It would be something completely alien

Comment: It's probably not possible to have an arthropod that big on Earth. The body plan isn't well suited for it, and it requires more oxygen in the atmosphere than we currently have. (At least, that's why they think ancient giant insects went extinct.)

Comment: @Halfthawed there already are plenty of arthropods that size. Tarantulas, giant beetles, stick insects, some large scorpions, land crabs, giant centipedes, giant millipedes, etc.

Comment: Four legs good, six legs better.

Answer (score 1):

They would most likely have a thick, chitinous exterior, to support their bodies. Their limbs would be thick, for support. They would likely breathe with trachea. Almost all other features will depend on what type of arthropod it is.